# Getting "collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status" in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, makefile

This is my Makefile for the compiler.

```
CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
AS = arm-none-eabi-as
LD = arm-none-eabi-ld
OD = arm-none-eabi-objdump

CFLAGS = -g -c -O1 -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb
AFLAGS = -g -c -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb
LDFLAGS = -g -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb --specs=rdimon.specs -lc -lrdimon
ODFLAGS = -d

all: HW1.elf

test: HW1.elf
        @ echo "...copying"
        qemu-system-arm  -machine versatilepb -cpu cortex-m3 -nographic -monitor null -serial null -semihosting -k\
ernel HW1.elf

HW1.elf: test.o t1.o
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) test.o t1.o -o HW1.elf

test.o: test.c t1.o
        @ echo ".compiling"
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) test.c t1.o -o test.o

t1.o: t1.s
        @ echo ".assembling"
        $(AS) $(AFLAGS) t1.s -o t1.o

clean:
        rm -rf t1.o test.o HW1.elf
```

When I do `make all`, I get

```
.assembling
arm-none-eabi-as -g -c -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb t1.s -o t1.o
.compiling
arm-none-eabi-gcc -g -c -O1 -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb test.c t1.o -o test.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc: warning: t1.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
arm-none-eabi-ld -g -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb --specs=rdimon.specs -lc -lrdimon test.o -o HW1.elf
arm-none-eabi-ld: unrecognised emulation mode: thumb
Supported emulations: armelf
make: *** [HW1.elf] Error 1
```

I have looked at numberous collect2 errors on StackOverflow and find that there is a function either not defined or is mislabeled.

I have entered the directory in the ~/.bashrc file to call arm-none-eabi library functions. I know that the error has nothing to do with the t1.s and/or test.c files and solely to do with an improper notation dealing with my makefile, but I'm lost as to what I'm doing wrong. I know it's something with `test.o`.

I will provide test.c and t1.s just in case there is something wrong with them.

test.c

```
include <stdio.h>

extern int inc(int);

#define RED_COUNT 5
#define YELLOW_COUNT 2
#define GREEN_COUNT 5

enum light_states {RED, YELLOW, GREEN};
static int state = RED;

void stop_light () {
  static int state_counter = 0;

  switch (state) {
  case RED:
    printf("RED\n");
    if (++state_counter >= RED_COUNT) {
      state_counter = 0;
      state = GREEN;
    }
    break;

  case GREEN:
    printf("GREEN\n");
    if (++state_counter >= GREEN_COUNT) {
      state_counter = 0;
      state = YELLOW;
    }
    break;

  case YELLOW:
    printf("YELLOW\n");
    if (++state_counter >= YELLOW_COUNT) {
      state_counter = 0;
      state = RED;
    }
    break;

  default:
    state = RED;
    state_counter = 0;
    break;
  }
}

main(){
  int i;

  while (i < 36) {
    stop_light();
    i = inc(i);
  }
}
```

t1.s

```
    .text
    .syntax unified
    .thumb
    .global inc
    .type   inc, %function
inc:
    adds    r0,r0,#1
    bx  lr
```

**EDIT 1:**
Updated the missing '-c' and am now getting a new error regarding LD.

**EDIT 2:**
Updated the LD error. Everything fixed now and answers were very helpful!

Comment: You forgot `-c` in the `CFLAGS`. Without that the makefile causes the build to attempt to link every object as an executable instead of just building it as a `.o`.

Comment: Do not use `ld` to link! Call the C compiler to link, it invokes `ld` with the correct options and operands.

Comment: Best to seperate in Makefiles compiling & linking.  The undefined references are things found in libc, so where is the right C library for your target architecture are you linking with something correctly built?

Comment: @kaylum ah thank you.

Comment: gcc has sensible default ld options for normal use which make it easier to use than ld, but they may not be correct if you're cross compiling and in this case gcc is trying to link and failing, because of missing -c option, pointed out by kaylum

Comment: @Rob11311 the files t1.s and test.c are given to us; built properly. We just need to create the makefile and i realize what FUZxxl was stating.